# WooCommerce Apply Coupon in cart page using Rest API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am Working the WooCommerce Rest API Version 2.
I am new in WooCommerce Rest API.
I have Read the [WooCommerce Rest API Docs](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#coupons) But I could not found Apply coupon API on the cart page.
I want to do the same as website in my application to apply coupon on the cart page. 
Can anyone help for the same?

Comment: @ajay, have you found anything on above ?

Comment: I have to make the custom endpoint for the apply coupon on the cart in the API request I accept the coupon code and customer id using it. First of all, validate coupon and then apply the coupon to the cart and update cart.

Comment: @Mr.Ajay . Hey Did you implement it, if so guide me on how you do it. or provide the code if possible.